# Installing Custom StyleCop Rule

Tags: c#, stylecop

In starting to create a custom StyleCop rule I have followed the instructions on the [Visual StyleCop Github](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/wiki/Writing-Custom-Rules-for-StyleCop).

• I've created a class, `MyStyleCopRules.cs`:

```
[SourceAnalyzer(typeof(CsParser))]
public class MyStyleCopRules : SourceAnalyzer
{
    public override void AnalyzeDocument(CodeDocument document)
    {
       ...
```

• Added an XML document, with the build action set to **EmbeddedResource**, called `MyStyleCopRules.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SourceAnalyzer Name="My StyleCop Rules">
    <Rules>
      <Rule Name="Fully Qualified Using Statements" CheckId="IS0001">
        <Context>Using statements must be fully qualifed.</Context>
        <Description>Fires when using statements are not fully qualifed.</Description>
      </Rule>
    </Rules>
</SourceAnalyzer>
```

**Other possibly pertinent facts:**

- This library is building, in release, at Framework 3.5.
- I have dropped a release build of this library in the same directory as StyleCop
- I use `StyleCop.MSBuild` (version 4.7.50) for the StyleCop integration, so I am copying it to `\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.{version}\tools`.
- The version of StyleCop referenced within the library, is the same as the one I am copying it next to. (I have checked the versions using ILSpy.)
- I am using Visual Studio 2015, but I am not using Analyzers

---

I don't see the rules when I open the `Settings.StyleCop` file, nor do I see any indication that they run with `Visual Studio`.

[image]

---

**What have I missed?**

Comment: i am facing problem that is my SO post . Can you help me ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60313440/custom-rule-stylecop-6-1-is-not-showing-on-setting-rule?fbclid=IwAR0craAtLQh5PCmHBEw_v0iSyxt3P6SAccIRT1Zs5Bgh9VBD_R9sN7tZsEo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Fully Qualified Using Statements` needs to have no spaces in it.

Namely:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SourceAnalyzer Name="My StyleCop Rules">
    <Rules>
      <Rule Name="FullyQualifiedUsingStatements" CheckId="IS0001">
        <Context>Using statements must be fully qualifed.</Context>
        <Description>Fires when using statements are not fully qualifed.</Description>
      </Rule>
    </Rules>
</SourceAnalyzer>
```